# Couldn't get text from a text field using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get value from a text field using selenium, but I am not able to. The value is neither present between the tags nor in the attribute "value".Please help me with this.

I have tried following ways but nothing worked.

```
Webelement.getAttribute("innerText");

Webelement.gettext();

Webelement.getAttribute("value");

Webelement.getAttribute("textcontent");
```

Below is the HTML for the text field.

```
<input name="quantityField_valueFieldKeyboard" id="quantityField_valueFieldKeyboard" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="false" maxlength="61" seyctype="numeric" class="seyc-visually-important seyc-ui-input-icon-white seyc-ui-input-text">
```

Comment: Which **value** are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: How are you defining the `Webelement`. Share the code for web element ?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("quantityField_valueFieldKeyboard")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Not getting any exception, the value captured is empty string " "

Comment: did u tried waits for the element whose text you are capturing ? Try that once,  use explicit wait

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("quantityField_valueFieldKeyboard")).getAttribute("value");
```

is correct way. You are getting empty string is also correct because your text field has no data in it. Since this is an input field, first enter some text and once text is saved. Try to fetch the entered text you will get your desired results.